# Git push failed "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: git, cron, push

I have the following commands in an executable file called 'git.run':

```
git add .
curtime=`date`
git commit -m "Automatic Backup @ $curtime"
git push origin master
```

The above script adds everything to the already made (local) repository called .git
A git commit is then labelled with the current date/time for auditing purposes
And then finally the local repository is pushed to a remote repository in bitbucket

When i run the following cron job:

```
* * * * * /var/www/ && ./git.run >> /var/www/jobs.log 2>&1
```

The following output is written to jobs.log...

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

However if i manually run

```
./git.run
```

from the /var/www directory; The entire script runs successfully and the repository is pushed to bitbucket and updated. Cron is working fine to the point that the executable is being run and returning a git error, plus the executable is sound/fine after running it manually which succeeds a push to a remote repository.

For testing purposes i have also tried:

```
* * * * * /var/www/git.run >> /var/www/jobs.log 2>&1
```

And this returns then same errors already described.

Ownership and permissions are as follows...

```
.git (repository) drwsrwsrwx for ubuntu user

git.run (script)  -rwxrwxrwx for ubuntu user
```

Can someone please show me where this is all going wrong!?!
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run that script from any folder, you can modify the git calls (in your script `git.run`) with:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www --git-dir=/var/www/.git xxx
```

(with `xxx` being `commit` or `status` or any other git command)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where would these amendments take place?

Comment: @fiatforever in the `git.run` script. The idea is to add options to any `git` command in order to specify the working tree and the `.git` folder path.